# Spatial correlogram of time series

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, spatial

I have the dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
  station = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20),
  vla = rpois(80,2),
  latitude = c(rep(40.7128, 20), rep(34.0522, 20), rep(41.8781, 20), rep(39.9526, 20)),
  longitude = c(rep(-74.0060, 20), rep(-118.2437, 20), rep(-87.6298, 20), rep(-75.1652, 20))
)

years <- rep(1979:1998, length.out = nrow(df))
df$year <- unlist(tapply(years, df$station, FUN = rep))
```

and I would like to create a correlogram to show that the correlation of vla between stations decreases with distance. I thought to calculate the Spearman correlation between each series and plot it against the corresponding distance. Do you have any suggestions?